# Android Studio Hardware & Software Device Emulation not working on MacOS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to use device emulation on a MacOS Big Sur 11.3 iMac, but when I try running Android R with a Pixel 4, I am presented with the following error:

[image]

I was reading on SO that sometimes this has to do with GPU incompatibilities and to try running using software emulation, so I tried downloading a Pixel 4 XL version without Google Play (so that I can modify the Emulated Performance Graphics to software), and when I run that device I receive the following error:

[image]

I've uninstalled/reinstalled Android Studio, I've also tried updating the device .ini to use the software config as well with no luck:

```
hw.gpu.enabled=no
hw.gpu.mode=off
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok confirming that this was a Big Sur Beta issue, I reverted down to a stable release and can run as expected :|

Comment: For reference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283524/android-emulator-not-working-or-showing-after-update-big-sur-11-3) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288329/android-device-manager-fails-to-launch-after-updating-to-macos-big-sur-11-3) there is a workaround for this issue that doesn't require downgrading OS